# Why enviroment variables don't work in vite project

Tags: firebase, environment-variables, vite, dotenv

I'm trying to work with environment variables in my Vite, Vue 3 and Firebase project but when I compile I get the following error: "process is not defined"

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import router from './router'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

const pinia = createPinia()

createApp(App)
  .use(pinia)
  .use(router)
  .mount('#app')
```

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  // configure Vite to recognize the "@" symbol as the "src" folder in your project, you can modify the "resolve.alias"
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    }
  },
})
```

En el "firebaseInit.js"

```
//"firebaseInit.js"

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID
}

const appFirebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default appFirebase;
```

if i try chance "process.env" for "import.meta.env" don't work to.

How can I properly configure the environment variables?

Comment: `apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY` What is `process`?  What value do you expect it to have?  You have not defined that variable.

Comment: That is precisely the question. I think the error should not appear if I have dotenv installed. Or am I suddenly misusing environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use prefix `VITE_` for all environment variables and then use them in you code with `import.meta.env`.

Example using file to set environment variables:

`.env.development` in project root folder:

```
VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY=abc123
```

`firebaseInit.js`:

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  ...
}
```

Build script in package.json:

```
build-dev: "vite build --mode development"
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your help, I solved it by putting the "VITE" prefix in the .env.

On the other hand,could you explain to me why you recommend creating a new script? Or do I have to do it when it goes to the production stage? I ask this because in the end I did not create the script `build-dev: "vite build --mode development` and when I run the "npm run dev" there was no error.

Very grateful for your time and response.

Comment: Using the `--mode` option is just to be more explicit. It's also useful when you have `development`/`test`/`production` environments with different values. If you only using `development`/`production` you can use the default script `dev` which builds for `development` and `build` that builds for `production`.